# C# - how to handle child threads in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am building a multi-threaded ASP.NET application.  I am new to writing multi-threaded apps.  I have a main class that spawns a number of threads that run while the application is being used.  The application has one main HTML page.  When the HTML page is first opened it calls the MyController.Start() method to create the threads and get them running.  Then the HTML page has a Javascript routine that continually polls an ASPX page in my application (every 2 seconds) to get data and display it.  There is a main class I called "MyController" that is the heart of the application.  It has a local boolean variable called Cancelled that is set to false.  The MyController spawns all of the child threads.  Each child thread has a loop that continues to execute as long as Cancelled = false.  One of the threads that is running is used as a monitor to make sure that the HTML page is still up and polling.  If this thread notices that 30 seconds have expired since the last time the HTML page polled then it changes the Cancelled variable to true.  Then one by one all of the threads finish running and close gracefully.

I need to be able to handle the situation where the user closes the browser and then reopens it before the 30 seconds has expired. I don't feel like I completely understand what the relationship is between the threads that get created and started and the instance of MyController.  Once threads are created and started do they just run independently of anything else?  I have a main static class called App that is used to provide easy access to the controller from anywhere in the application.  The way I have it coded right now I think that I am creating new threads every time that the HTML page is loaded.  So if the user were to close the HTML page and then reopen it I think then I would have two instances of every thread running.  Is that correct?  If so, how can I check to see if those threads are already running so that I don't create new instances of them?

Hope this makes sense!  Thanks in advance for any help.  Here is my code.

Start.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(App._myController == null)
  {
    App._myController = new MyController();
  }
  App._myController.Start();
}
```

Library code

```
public class App
{
  public static MyController _myController {get;set;}
  static App()
  {
    _myController = new MyController();
  }
}

public class MyController
{
  public bool Cancelled {get;set;}
  private object SyncLock = new object();
  Thread _thread1;
  Thread _thread2;
  Thread _thread3;

  public void Start()
  {
    this.Cancelled = false;
    _thread1 = new Thread(Worker1);
    _thread1.Start();

    _thread2 = new Thread(Worker2);
    _thread2.Start();

    _threadMonitor = new Thread(Monitor);
    _threadMonitor.Start();
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    lock(this.SyncLock)
    {
      this.Cancelled = true;
    }
  }

  private void Worker1()
  {
    while(!Cancelled)
    {
      ..do some stuff..
    }
  }

  private void Worker2()
  {
    while(!Cancelled)
    {
      ..do some stuff..
    }
  }

  private void Monitor()
  {
    while(!Cancelled)
    {
      ..check database to see when last poll was
      ..if last poll is greater than 30 seconds ago
      {
        this.Stop();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: have you tried setting your threads with `myThread.IsBackground = true;`?

Comment: Let me make one more important comment.  This is not a "normal" ASP.NET application.  It is being built for a customer to run on a single, isolated laptop by a single user with IIS running locally, disconnected from the internet.  This is not a normal multi user ASP.NET application.  Hope that clears some things up.

Comment: @FlorisPrijt - how would setting IsBackground = true help?

Comment: The thing with IsBackground set to true is that if the main thread where it executes on closes, that all the background threads are automatically being terminated as well. Although I am not certain if this would work for asp.net pages, hence why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not in love with your design, but that's a separate question. I'll address your current problem with your current design...

From your `Start()` function, if the threads are not null, set `Cancelled` to true and `Join()` the threads, then continue with your existing functionality.

```
  public void Start()
  {
    this.Cancelled = true;

    if (_thread1 != null) _thread1.Join();
    // repeat for other threads

    this.Cancelled = false;
    _thread1 = new Thread(Worker1);
    _thread1.Start();

    _thread2 = new Thread(Worker2);
    _thread2.Start();

    _threadMonitor = new Thread(Monitor);
    _threadMonitor.Start();
  }
```

As for a better approach, maybe a service to do the background work that would interface with your page using WCF (perhaps using REST).

Comment: Won't _thread1 always be null when Start is run? Or, is it that because App._myController is a static member, _thread1 will still have the reference to the thread if you run Start a second time?

Comment: @CoreyBurnett it will only be null the first time. Since you've assigned this to a static variable, you're only creating this class once.

Answer (score 2):

> I am building a multi-threaded ASP.NET application. I am new to
>   writing multi-threaded apps. I have a main class that spawns a number
>   of threads that run while the application is being used.

Noooo. You are not supposed to do that. Spawning a new thread from ASP.NET is a fair way to shoot yourself in a foot. Why? Because each new request generally gets a dedicated thread from ASP.NET thread pool. There is a very limited number of threads that you can get (hence number of logically concurrent requests). If a request spawns another manual thread - odd things will happen, starting from memory leaks, deadlocks and ending up crashing your application or web server.

Once a request is processed, your server should completely forget about the user.

Instead, consider different approach. Maintain state in:

- Database
- User cookie
- Html hidden fields
- ASP.NET containers that get serialized/deserialized by ASP.NET itself

Restore the state on new each request and compare the timings.

Comment: Well, this is not a normal ASP.NET application.  It will run on a dedicated laptop and only have one user.  In fact, it will not even be connected to the internet.  Under those circumstances do you still think this would be a problem?

Comment: Unless you are far away with the current approach, I would try to change it to the stateless design and a single threaded approach (each new requests gets a new single thread). It is easier to write, debug and it is a well-known simple model that works globally on a scale of the Internet.

Comment: Ok. But I have a number of concurrent processes that need to run at the same time.  I have 3 different pieces of hardware that are connected to the laptop.  The application needs to be able to communicate with these things and retrieve data from them through various mechanisms and at various times.  The main HTML page needs to aggregate all of this data and display it.  I thought originally about writing Windows services but instead decided to use the multi-threaded approach.  These processes need to run independently and talk to the different pieces of hardware.

Comment: It is sort of a "real time" display for the data being collected from the different pieces of hardware.  There is a main database that is used as the central repository.  The different threads talk to the different pieces of hardware and get data on different schedules.  They all save it to the database.  Then the main HTML page simply requests the latest data from the database and displays it.  I'm not sure how I could do this in an ASP.NET application without using threads or multiple Windows Services.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett what you're doing begs for a Windows Service to talk to the hardware and write to the database. The ASP page would simply pull data from the database as needed. This is a simpler solution that what you're doing, it will run better, and be easier to maintain.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett totally agree with Jon

Comment: Hmm. Well, thanks for the input.  It has helped me a lot.  Unfortunately I am very, very far along in the development.  The system works well and doesn't seem to have any memory leaks.  But I do understand what you are saying and that a Windows Service may have been the better way to go.  Perhaps if we build a version 2 we can move to a Windows Service.  I really appreciate the advice and for you taking time out of your day to help!